# Rewrite Url with out extension

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I am using Intelligencia for my url-rewrite functionality.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false"
        type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
</configSections>
```

The below rule its working fine for my search page

```
<rewrite url="~/search/(.+).aspx" to="~/search.aspx?type=$1"/>
```

but i need to write my search page with below rule

```
<rewrite url="~/search/(.+)" to="~/search.aspx?type=$1"/>
```

If i run with above rule i am getting page not found error.

Plz advice me is there any setting in IIS.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use asp.net routing? I find it to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Which url is causing the page not found error?

Comment: <rewrite url="~/search/(.+)" to="~/search.aspx?type=$1"/>
for this rule i am getting page not found error.

Comment: but you're navigating a specific page for getting page not found. I'd like to know which url is not matching

Comment: http://www.xxx.com/search/c   If i open like this in browser its says page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article (with a downloadable solution sample) to use Routes to map to extensionless "SEO Friendly" urls:

http://goo.gl/BBnsa